# ServiceStack SelfHosted Site Default page

Tags: servicestack

I have tried all the Razor self-hosted and the servicestack templates and in those projects it is possible to serve static html and cshtml if you have the razorFormat installed.  I don't know what I am doing wrong and I have just copied code into new solutions and I cannot get html responses to work.  I can get the metadata page always and the services work.  I am not able to add default.htm and get it to work.
If I type in `http://localhost:1337` I should get directed to the default page.  Maybe I am missing something but I don't know what it is.  If someone can give me a hand I would appreciate it greatly!

Here is my default.htm

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    SOMETEXT
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Program

```
class Program
    {
        [Route("/hello")]
        [Route("/hello/{Name}")]
        public class Hello
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class HelloResponse
        {
            public string Result { get; set; }
        }

        public class HelloService : Service
        {
            public object Any(Hello request)
            {
                return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
            }
        }

        public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase {
            public AppHost() : base("StarterTemplate HttpListener",                             typeof(HelloService).Assembly) {
            }

            public override void Configure(Funq.Container container) {
                container.Register(new HelloService());
            }    
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listeningOn = args.Length == 0 ? "http://*:1337/" : args[0];
            var appHost = new AppHost();
            appHost.Init();
            appHost.Start(listeningOn);

            Console.WriteLine("AppHost Created at {0}, listening on {1}", DateTime.Now, listeningOn);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Edit:
I should have added what the response I am getting is.

```
Handler for Request not found: 


Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.PathInfo: /default.htm
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /default.htm
```

One more thing that I tried was to put a request filter in at AppHostHttpListenerBase.Configure.  I do not ever even hit that in my project but I do in the template projects.

EDIT:
I found out that the problem is that my Default.html and app.Config files are not getting moved to the bin/Debug directory. Has anyone experienced that problem?

Comment: Don't the ServiceStack examples use Razor view pages (*.cshtml)? Try changing `default.html` to `default.cshtml`?

Comment: I have tried that also.  If I don't use razor I should still get the default.htm to work.  I don't have this problem in my other project that started as an empty asp.net project.  I want the flexibility to self host so that I can chose to run as a service or as a Linux daemon.

Comment: You need to set the 'Build-Action' on all content files you wish to be auto copied into the /bin dir to 'Copy if Newer'.

Comment: Thanks for the help mythz.  I realized that was my problem shortly after writing my last edit.  Now that I think about it I even remember reading somewhere that that was necessary (probably a post from you) and it just didn't register I guess.  Thanks for the help again and fantastic framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a good blog post](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/12/self-hosting-servicestack-serving.html) on serving Razor pages for a self-hosted/console app. I don't think you need an app.config or web.config file, though I could be wrong.

The two things I think that you're missing:

1) Add `Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat())` to the Configure method in your AppHost
2) Change 'Copy to Output Directory' value to 'Copy if newer' for your Razor files (this is within the Properties settings of the file). Also, change your `default.htm` file to `default.cshtml`.

Comment: Thanks for the help paaschpa.  You are definitely correct about the Copy To Output Directory.  I believe you are incorrect about the 1st point though.  Servicestack doesn't care if the file is default.htm or default.cshtml.  The only reason to include the RazorFormat plugin is if you are going to be using razor.  ServiceStack will serve content pages either way.

Answer (score 0):

For xamarin in OS X 'Copy to Output Directory' will definitely be a pain in the ass, because you should select this option on each file, and sometimes twice. So another option is create symbolic link

```
ln -s /path_to_project/assets /path_to_project/bin/Debug/assets 
ln -s /path_to_project/Views /path_to_project/bin/Debug/Views
```

It's very useful for hundreds of files in assets and just a little bit easier for Views folder.

*The same can be done on Linux hosting to hide selfhost.exe and *.dll in bin folder*